# Not able to delete fan comment on YouTube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using the following call to delete comment:

```shell
curl --location --request DELETE \
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=Ugy3_0iu-ldT5YDxtKF4AaABAg&key=...' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'
```

to delete a comment. The comment ID in this `curl` is brand comment which I was able to delete.

However if I replace it with fan comment ID:

```
UgzwMv7063oH0moz_654AaABAg
```

from permalink to that comment:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLRKpnrzkGc&lc=UgzwMv7063oH0moz_654AaABAg`

I get this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
                "domain": "youtube.comment",
                "reason": "processingFailure",
                "location": "id",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id in the peralink its not nessasarly the same as the comment id.

You should do a [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) first and find the comment you wish to delete and use the id from that to preform the delete.